# How to hide visio shape group in stencil

Tags: shapes, visio, stencils, shapesheet

I have a complex stencil with many small shapes (sheet.6 to 43), grouped in a group (sheet.44). There is also sub-groups in it.

I want to hide this group using shapesheet formulas to use a user propertie.

On a simple shape I would set :
Geometry1.NoShow=sheet.44!user.isHidden
Miscellaneous.HideText=sheet.44!user.isHidden

But how to make it inherited in all sub shapes ? with vba ?

***Edit with Answer :***

Thank you Jon for corfirming that there is no other way than VBA.
Here is my VBA code for all of you who are having the same problem.

```
Call makeithidden("Sheet.164!Geometry1.NoShow", myshape)


Sub makeithidden(formula As String, ByVal myshape As Shape)
    For Each subShape In myshape.Shapes
        subShape.Cells("geometry1.noShow").FormulaForceU = formula
        subShape.Cells("HideText").FormulaForceU = formula
        Call makeithidden(formula, subShape)
    Next subShape
End Sub
```

See you guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VBA code would have to loop through all the sub shapes and set that formula up, any time the group gets a new shape. The format of the formula would be just like your example, so it wouldn't be too hard to do:

```
SubShp.CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent,0,2).FormulaU = "Sheet." & Cstr(ParShp.ID) & "!Geometry1.NoShow"
```

or something like that, where that's in a loop for each SubShp in ParShp.Shapes...